# Gradle Plugin Update 3.5.0 is making activity to destroy in backstack

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I am just having a weird behavior where after updating to latest android Gradle plugin, causing my home activity to get destroyed automatically when I go from home to search and coming back it just closes the app instead of getting back to home. I have not changed anything else. I am wondering how a plugin can change the in-app behavior of an app.

the current version is

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'`

I can confirm that it was working fine on 3.3.2 with no code change

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
```

I am starting my activity as follow. and have added no flags at all.

```
search_et.clickWithDebounce {
        activity!!.startActivityForResult(
            Intent(activity, SearchActivity::class.java),
            SearchConstants.SEARCH_REQUEST_CODE
        )
    }
```

I have tried using the latest version of Gradle also but no luck. Currently, im using `5.4.1` but tried updating to 5.6.1 also. My android studio version is 3.5 stable. Can anybody add some insights why this is happening and what is a workaround to eliminate this behavior?

Comment: If you downgrade to 3.3.2 does it still happen?

Comment: haven't tried but expects it to work as it is working till 3.3.2, if you want i can give it a shot. @ScottCooper

Comment: Give it a try because I can't see how the gradle version changes the build

Comment: it's working @ScottCooper at 3.3.1 & 3.3.2 both but going above is what causing problem i guess.